Is there a function $f$ for which the following is not true?
I was working with the geometric series
$$1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n \qquad |x| < 1$$
for which the sum is known to be
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n = \frac{1}{1-x} \qquad |x| < 1$$
After working through exercises in my Calculus Textbook, I realized and therefore theorized the following
If $f$ is a continuous function on some interval $D$, then the following is true for some interval $I$, where $I\in D$
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(f(x)\right)^n = \frac{1}{1-f(x)}
\end{equation}
Is there a function, $f$, such that this is not true?

As long as $|f(x)|>1$ in $D$

That equality is try exactly when $|f(x)|<1,$ so to find a counter example, you can pick, say $f(x)=1+e^x$ and $D=\mathbb R.$

Answ: yes, e.g. $f(x)=2$.

$I\in D$ means $I$ is an element of $D$, which is absurd. I think you mean $I\subseteq D$.

Thank you @LidingYao, ThomasAndrews, and Anne Bauval, indeed, whenever $|f(x)| > 1$ the equality breaks, I now realize that also from the fact that the geometric series converges only when $|x|<1$.

Every constant function $f(x)=c$ for $|c|\geq 1$ is an example where the equality fails or rather is meaningless (since the series diverges).
On the other hand if $|f(x)|<1$ for all $x$ then indeed the equality holds. Even if $f$ is discontinuous. It's a simple rule of function composition.

Thank you @freakish. I hadn't realized that even if $f$ is discontinuous, the equality still holds given that $|f(x||<1$
